# Optimizing Flex application - Where to find my bottlenecks

Tags: apache-flex, optimization, web-applications

My **Flex web application** is almost ready for launch. I'm currently optimizing as much as I can in order to make sure even low-end clients are able to run it fluently. The problem is, I have no idea where to optimize more than I've already optimized.

My question is, **what are the usuals suspects regarding bottlenecks**? What tips and experiences do you have when it comes to Optimizing a Flex app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some web tutorials on this, [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/dcoletta/optimizing-flex-applications) looks helpful. And of course, the Flex profiler could help you identifying the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good presentation covering a lot of pitfalls. Another thing I can think of is over-usage of bindings in large applications. They're easy to create and forget, silently generating a lot extra code running in the background, and are especially potent when used carelessly on entire classes.

Answer (score 1):

These are some of the things I've seen that cause slow downs. I've only worked with one or two Flex developers, so I don't know if this is obvious, or helpful. Either way:

- Transparency: Whenever views have a lot of components with non-opaque transparency (i.e. alpha less than 1.0), these views tend to be extremely slow, especially on older machines.
- Object Creation: It seems that whenever there is a lot of object creation happening, the app slows to a crawl, even on newer machines. I worked on an app that created at least a few hundred objects when the application started.
- Data Fetching: Whenever data is loaded asynchronously, the app will take a performance hit depending on how much is loaded
- Lots of objects: When views have lots of objects in them, they tend to lag and generally drag ass.

Those are the ones I remember the best, having not worked on a major Flex app in over a year.

Answer (score 1):

Other than performance improvements you can optimize the file size of flex applications.That will definately improve user experience.I hope this article helps: 
http://askmeflash.com/article/9/optimize-flex-swf-filesize-performance-loading